# Undertow: PathHandler works with websockets, RoutingHandler does not

Tags: java, websocket, undertow, java-websocket

I am putting together a little app with Undertow. I have two websocket endpoints, but I am having trouble with getting the handler the way I want.

If I define my handler this way, things work well:

```
            handler = path()
                .addPrefixPath("/websocket", websocket(new WSTest()))
                .addPrefixPath("/battery", websocket(batteryStatusSender))
                .addPrefixPath("/", resource(new ClassPathResourceManager(getClass().getClassLoader(), getClass().getPackage()))
                    .addWelcomeFiles("index.html"));
```

If I define it the way I *want* (I'll be doing some REST, so I want to separate out POST, PUT, and GET):

```
            handler = new RoutingHandler()
                .get("/websocket", websocket(new WSTest()))
                .get("/battery", websocket(batteryStatusSender))
                .get("/", resource(new ClassPathResourceManager(getClass().getClassLoader(), getClass().getPackage()))
                    .addWelcomeFiles("index.html"));
```

This works sometimes, and sometimes does not; connections to /websocket never seem to make it to my onConnect() in WsTest and BatteryStatusSender, both of which are WebSocketConnectionCallback objects.

Is there something I am missing about RoutingHandler?